# Is there a standard way to access the windows services file in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, wmi

Is there a standard way in .Net to access and modify the windows services file? Right now I'm just accessing the file via a stream and writing to the file like I would for any other file. The file is located in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\, but I'm worried that this may change in 64 bit versions of Windows or may vary in different versions of Windows (I could be wrong and admittedly, I haven't looked into this very much yet). Aside from that, I'm just wondering if there is a standard way, say via WMI and/or the System.Management namespace, to find and modify the services file.

The actual specifics of what I need to do is to check if certain database aliases used for our software are specified for the expected ports. If not, add them.

Comment: The path is the same in Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Ok, that's makes me very happy.

Comment: That file does not limit what ports you may use in any way. It is simply a primitive name service for ports, allowing you to specify them by name instead of number.

Comment: Ya that's what we actually use it for... We do [database alias name] [port number]/tcp [comment on what it is]

Comment: Usually this is used for IANA assigned known services - which probably doesn't include your databases. I don't want to condemn your practice, but it _is_ already nonstandard. Whatever way you use to modify the file.

Comment: Unfortunately, we do a lot of things "the wrong way"... don't get me started ;) Anyway, we'll have to continue supporting it this way for the time being. I was just wondering if there is a better way edit the services file, since I'm stuck using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An open source project called System.Peppers has a class doing this.

There is a registry key that contains the full path to the files you are editing.

Here is a link to the exact class: [HostFile class](http://systempeppers.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/35244#165383)

Comment: Nice work Jonathan. That's a sweet library you've got going on there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the System.Management.Instrumentation namespace

Sample code here 
http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=114

Answer (score 0):

you can use System.Environment.SystemDirectory to get to the sys32 folder